# Effects of microgravity on spinal disc thickness

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, tensor-calculus, weight

Image is data of spinal thickness in micro-gravity or suspension experiment.
[image]

I was reading an experiment on spinal changes due to microgravity in astronauts. Researchers simulated microgravity spinal elongation by suspending human subjects in air so that  no part of their body touched the ground.

This figure shows the % change in disc thickness for each subject compared to data obtained from astronauts in space.

I am trying to determine what is the best explanation for the significant difference in the spinal changes between the two groups:

1 - The mass of the volunteers did not decrease as it does in microgravity

**2 - The weight of the body in the lab is still acting on the cartilage**

3 - Volunteers were not suspended upside down to account for fluid accumulation in the head and neck

4 - Gravitational force is converted to tension in microgravity

I think the best explanation is that suspension does not eliminate gravity, so there will be stretching forces at all places where the subjects were attached to suspension wires. This would cause an even greater elongation of the spine than just the absence of gravity, since now I have a tension (T) opposing the weight of the subject on their spine, and the net force will cause the tissue to deform.

Would this be as simple as $F_{Net} = ma = T - mg$

so $T = ma + mg = m (a+g)$ which is greater then the stretching force on spine that occurs simply by the lack of gravity in space.

Is there a better way to calculate this, or to explain it?

I am assuming the bodies in the experiment were suspended vertically (head up). I can find no reason for the discrepancy if the bodies had been suspended horizontally since there would be NO difference between the net force on the spine in a horizontal position and when in microgravity.

**Original article**

[image]

Comment: Could you link the source? I think seeing the experiment for myself could help me understand what your question is.

Comment: Sure. I added entire original article to OP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell your statement is essentially correct.

In the lab the person is suspended but there is no change in effective gravity. This provides a stretching force on each disc; tension pointed upwards and gravity pointed downwards. For that scenario one would expect roughly uniform increase in disc thickness, which is experimentally confirmed.

In microgravity there is no force; one would expect from the lack of effective gravity that the discs spread out, impeded by the bones and fluid from its extra inertia resulting in the most increase in the thoracic region.

**Note** however that that is just one hypothesis which assumes uniform characteristics for all discs (and does not explain the relatively low increase in the lumbar region). Without further research into the biology of it I cannot say if the hypothesis is actually correct.